# Angular , md-button naming

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have my code like ,

```
<md-button type="submit" class="md-primary">
    Log In
</md-button>
```

I want to name my each button to a specific name , can i just name it like name="something" or is there something standard i should follow ?

Comment: Really unclear what you are asking. Anything with `"submit"` really just submits the form. You really should expand your example to make your intention clear as to what you want to use the `"name"` for.

Comment: Please check the Angular naming convention documentation: https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#naming

Comment: @Amit The OP is referencing AngularJS and your link points to the Angular 4.x docs.

Answer (score 0):

Controller:

```
$scope.btnAttrName = "someAttrName";
$scope.btnDisplayName = "someDisplayName";
```

HTML:

```
<md-button name="{{btnAttrName}}">
  {{btnDisplayName}}
</md-button>
```